# Rake task doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have this rake task in a Rails 3.2.11 application in `lib/rake/searches.rb`:

```
namespace :searches do
  desc "Start background searches"
  task :start => :environment do
    Rails.logger.info "Starting searches..."
    Campaign.all.each do |c|
      next unless c.recurring?

      Rails.logger.info "Starting searches for campaign '#{c.name}'"
      SearchWorker.enqueue(:campaign_id => c.id, :clear => true)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it locally everything goes well. When I run it in production it errors out:

```
$ bundle exec rake searches:start
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SearchWorker
/var/apps/web/lib/tasks/searches.rake:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/apps/web/lib/tasks/searches.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => searches:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I jump into a console session, I can see that the class is correctly auto loaded:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> SearchWorker
=> SearchWorker
```

This workers live in `app/workers` and they are added to the `autoload_paths` config setting in application.rb:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
config.autoload_paths += %W(
    #{config.root}/custom_scripts
    #{config.root}/app/workers
    #{config.root}/app/models/filters
)
```

So I have no clue why the error only occurs in production, and when running from a rake task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake searches:start

Comment: @house9 I did, same results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have created the rake file with .rb extension

```
lib/rake/searches.rb
```

can you try changing it to

```
lib/rake/searches.rake
```

That should work

Comment: That's not the case: 
`$ ls -la lib/tasks/searches*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 349 Jan 31 06:12 lib/tasks/searches.rake`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the production environment in Rails 3.2 not being fully loaded, after the `:environment` task is complete.

If you explicitly require `SearchWorker` ie.

```
require 'app/workers/search_worker'
```

Within the beginning of the task block, it'll work.

(Why auto-loads isn't doing this for you, I don't know)

Comment: It could be because they added threadsafe!.  I recently added that and one of the fallouts was that my workers were no longer autoloading in rake tasks.